# Page Redirection Testing with qUnit

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, .net, qunit

I have the following function

```
var redirect = function() {
    window.location.href = "http://www.google.com";
}
```

I want to test this function using `qUnit`. When I run the test cases, I am getting a "Permission Denied" error. How do I fix this?

Comment: I assume it is something about the user rights.